# Create & populate new column using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create column which will store values 10,100,1000,10000,100000 & so on . How can it be efficiently done using a for loop?

Comment: Multiply by `10` per iteration. And by column do you mean array? And please specify the programming language.

Comment: Sequencing is not the issue but how do I formally write it that is my question.Right from adding the column to populating values.Would be great if you can help

Comment: Please specify the programming language.

Comment: How to do this in R?

Comment: Take a variable put 1 in it and then start the for loop and then multiply variable a by 10. And then assign that value to a again.

Comment: I know the logic all I am asking is the formal code.Thanks

Comment: Added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along this idea

```
 arr <- c(10)

 faktor = 10
 val = 10
 for (i in 1:10){arr[i] = val; val = val * faktor}
```

I'm sure one can it have simpler/cheaper. But this is loop, isn't it ;-)